# insert php-value in IMG CODE

Tags: php, image, insert, height

I have searched for a php code to generate a specific height of an image.

Eg `<img src = "picture.jpg" width = "20" HEIGH = "VAUE FROM TEST.PHP">`

The idea is to create the image of a thermometer that gets higher because of the higher value of the php file

The php file contains only numbers so results will be `<img src = "picture.jpg" width = "20" height = "16">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your question completely, but I think you want to know how to display height value in html

```
<img src = "picture.jpg" width = "20" height = "<?php echo $height;?>">
```

where $height will be passed from php file to html

Comment: Thanks, it works like i wanted ;)
Problem is when the value goes negative ;(

Anyway, i learned something new